# How can you check if your built in hdmi port is working under ubuntu 10.4? and what software would be needed?

Tags: ubuntu

i've installed ubuntu 10.4 on my acer aspire 5920G laptop with built in hdmi and firewire and would like to use it on my hdtv + i'm looking at buying an external hard drive that uses firewire. Is there a way to check these ports are working before i buy and if not what would i install to get them to work.

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may find some help here: http://amahanty.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/watching-movies-on-tv-using-hdmi-support-in-ubuntu-10-04/